# How to set text with angular data like this <siya> in dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i am binding list of data which contains data with angular brackets and i need to fill in dropdownlist with angular text as mentioned.But when i bind it converts it into lt format instead of angular bracket.
How to show Text with angular brackets.Please Suggest.

Answer (score 0):

use

& l t ; //for <

& g t ; // for >

For more html entities visit this link [DEMO](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Comment: You need to remove the space between the letters. &lt;siya&gt;

Comment: Thanks @KarthikDV if I write without space in code block then its converted to its symbols so i use spaces.